# iPhone Simulator Keyboard iOS7.0

Tags: ios-simulator

I just installed Xcode 6.0. I'm trying to replicate a problem some users are having with the keyboard covering some items. I have my target set to 7.0 and the simulator set to iPad2. However, the keyboard still looks like the iOS 8.0 keyboard - with the extra row at the top where the device tries to guess what word I am typing. That extra row covers a textfield in the app but I don't think the older keyboard would.

Is there a way to get the simulator to, you know, simulate 7.0 instead of 8.0? Am I missing  a setting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your deployment target just sets what the minimum supported OS version is for your project.  You actually need to choose an iOS 7.0 device from the run destinations menu in Xcode.

Make sure you've installed the iOS 7.0 runtime from Xcode's Preferences.  Note that 7.0 is only supported on Mavericks.  iOS 7.1 is supported on both Mavericks and Yosemite.